# Change resolution of grub2

Tags: fedora, grub2

I have a 4k high-DPI laptop screen and I would like to scale or change its resolution so that the text isn't tiny.

I have tried setting the `GRUB_GFXMODE` variable to `"1920x1200"`, `"1920x1200x32"` and `"1920x1200x16"` but that did nothing. I tried running `vbeinfo`, `vbeprobe` and `videoinfo` in the grub terminal to try to find the available video modes, but grub complained about not being able to find any of those commands.

How do I set the resolution for grub2?

I am running a very fresh installation of Fedora 36 in a Lenovo P1.

Comment: Are you sure that it is grub which complained about not being able to find these commands ? Yes ? then you almost certainly did not use them appropriately. No ? in fact it's your shell ? would you be more lucky using **hwinfo --framebuffer** (as root)

Comment: It worked for me but I've stopped using it for some reasons:

`GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080x24,1024x768x32,auto"
GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND="all_video"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"`